# How to enable ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server in PHP 7+?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, php-7.2

I am running CentOS 7, so I followed the instructions here (for the RHEL 7 entry) and it was successful at each step.

Link I followed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

I'm kind of stuck now, as I know I have to configure something on the PHP (v7.2.9) side to get it to "see" this installation. I don't know where the "extension(s)" actually got installed to, so I'm not sure how to modify the PHP.ini file, and not sure how to set up the connection string in PHP to test it.

I'm currently using odbc_connect() to test (if that helps or not).

Can you provide steps once the above link's instructions are followed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as it usually happens, did some digging and was able to find answer after a buddy reminded me about the /etc/odbcinst.ini file... for future Googlers and So'ers:

1. sudo vi /etc/odbcinst.ini

You should see something like this (assuming you followed instructions for your Distro to the T without any errors - link in original post):

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1
UsageCount=1
```

So... once that's confirmed, create a basic PHP file to test. I'm using PHP 7.2.9 here:

```
<?php

// Configuration Settings for connection to Database
$host = 'SERVERNAME';
$user = 'dbuser';
$pass = 'dbpass';
$db   = 'InstanceName';
$conn = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=$host;PORT=1433;DATABASE=$db";

// Open connection
$db_connect = odbc_connect($conn, $user, $pass);

// Check for successful connection
if ( $db_connect ) {
    echo 'Beer time!';
} else {
    die('Error connecting...');
}

?>
```

The important part is ensuring the "name" of the driver as it shows in between the [] in the odbcinst file match the name of the DRIVER you use in the connection string of the PHP file between the {}. In this case (defaults), it's "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server".

Hope that helps someone else out. I struggled with it for a while.